# disable border collapse separate with rowspan

Tags: html, css, html-table, border-spacing

I have a problem, here is the table that I am trying to implement in html:

[needed result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoDqG.png)

For now I have this result:

[actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RqYH.png)

with this code :

```
<style>
    table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 0 10px;
    }

    th,
    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 8px;
        text-align: left;
    }
</style>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>column1</th>
                <th>column2</th>
                <th>column3</th>
                <th>column4</th>
                <th>column5</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">Monday</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">Tuesday</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

I need to find a way to remove the space between 2 lines inside a line that have a rowspan.
Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`border-spacing` is messing things up a bit, the simplest solution I can think of is:

1. set `border-spacing: 0;`
2. add empty row before each day of the week `<tr class="break"></tr>` that will act as a desired space/break
3. add styles for the break `.break {height: 10px;}`

full code:

```
<style>
    table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 0;
    }

    th,
    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 8px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    
    .break {
        height: 10px;
    }
</style>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>column1</th>
            <th>column2</th>
            <th>column3</th>
            <th>column4</th>
            <th>column5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="break"></tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Monday</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="break"></tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Tuesday</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, do you know if I used a css frameword like bootstrap it will have been easier ?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve, if your app is quite small then such framework will make it unnecessary heavier, or if you were learning then I would fiddle with plain html+css (maybe also js) to learn how all those things work and only use framework when you would be able to write the same code but don't want to waste time to reinvent the wheel